# Spring Data JpaRepository batched .save() then .flush() results in duplicate key exception

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

according to many posts on here the JpaRepository Abstraction should behave like a CrudRepository. Meaning upon calling the .save(entity) Method an INSERT or UPDATE will be performed based on whether the key already exists or not.
I have a simple use case where I consume an update event, collect a list of Entities, apply the necessary changes to those Entities and persist that list back as update.
I'm using a Postgres DB, JPA and hibernate

```
@Entity(name = EPISODE_RESEARCH_TABLE)
data class EpisodeEntity(
    override val created: OffsetDateTime,
    override val externalId: String?,
    @Id
    override val id: String,
    override var modified: OffsetDateTime,
    override val title: String
)

@Service
class EpisodeService(
    private val repository: JpaRepository<EpisodeEntity, String>
) : <..> {

    override fun modelFromEntity(entity: EpisodeEntity): EpisodeResearch =
        <...>

    override fun entityFromModel(model: EpisodeResearch): EpisodeEntity =
        <...>

    override fun update(models: Collection<EpisodeResearch>): Set<EpisodeResearch> =
        models
            <...>
            .map { repository.save(it) }
            .also { repository.flush() }
            <...>

    override fun create(models: Collection<EpisodeResearch>): Set<EpisodeResearch> =
        update(models)

    override fun delete(models: Collection<EpisodeResearch>): Set<EpisodeResearch> =
        <...>

}
```

the configs show:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=1000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.autocommit=false
```

upon executing the .save()'s and the final .flush() the logs show

> HHH000315: Exception executing batch [java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into episode_research (created, external_id, modified, title, id) values (<...>) was aborted: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "episode_research_pkey"
> Detail: Key (id)=(<...>) already exists.  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.], SQL: insert into episode_research (created, external_id, modified, title, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

so it's obvious that the query exectued is just a simple INSERT which is bound to fail on such an operation.

So the question here is:
**Why is the behaviour different from what should be expected?** Afterall there isn't even an explicit update Method provided with these abstractions.

there is an option provided by [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update) utilizing the EntityManager, however that would require a lengthy discussion with a colleague who is completely dead-set on only using the CrudRepository abstractions which I'd just rather avoid

Comment: Spring and hibernate have a complex interaction. 1st, you don't need to call `flush()` as the Hibernate will automatically flush at the end of a transaction. 2nd you probably need to annotate the service or method `update` with `@Transactional` to share the unit of work between the `save()` and `flush()` calls. If you annotate the method, you must ensure all calls to `update` from other methods in the same class are annotated with `@Transactional` (rinse and repeat).